# Insertion failed when used Asp.Net Mvc, Linq, Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add row to table using asp.net mvc kendo ui. But for the first time, it is a success. when do second time, the debugging pointer says "The process or thread has been changed since the last step" and try to add the first insertion values also. Since the table does not allow the duplication of primary key the insertion fails at second time. Please advie.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Insert([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, AdminHeaderImage batchModel)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (var Entity = new DealerEntities())
                    {                    
                        Entity.AdminHeaderImages.AddObject(batchModel);
                        Entity.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

public ActionResult Index()
        {


            using (var Entity = new DealerEntities())
            {
                var outPut = Entity.AdminHeaderImages.ToList();
                return View(outPut);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is AdminHeaderImage?  How is it defined?  How is your table defined?  Kendo has nothing to do with this.

Comment: AdminHeaderImage is just a table name on my db.It contains a primary key and another one column only and this column does not allow duplication. Insertion is okay for the first time. But on second time,
"The process or thread has been changed since the last step" happens and try to insert the first time values also. Pls help

Comment: @MystereMan, can't you get from the above code that `Entity.AdminHeaderImages` means object.entityname?

Comment: @DotNetDreamer - I have no idea what you mean by object.entityname, I was asking for how it was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your Entity object is shared between requests.

I recommend having an entity object per web request.

This article explains more

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/05/18/how-to-manage-objectcontext-per-request-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: pls suggest me how to recode it for having entity object per web request.

Comment: How exactly is Entity shared when it's created new in each request?

Comment: Entity is added to the Model. My controller is named as DefaultController. On Index , its View is strongly typed  with one table from entity in Model. On this view I have a Kendo Grid where these CRUD operations carry on.Yes there is one Layout page also for this view. Please advice.

Comment: Just create the helper class mentioned in the link and call its GetCurrentContext method (which should return your Entity context) whenever you need to use the Entity object.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the following code at the end of Insert which would refresh my entity.

"return Json(new [] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));"

This solved my problem.